# Subnetting new address cannot connect to internet

Tags: dhcp

I re subnetted our network from 10.1.24.1-254 subnet 255.255.255.0

To 10.1.24.1-10.1.25.254 subnet 255.255.254.0

I've changed all the devices subnets.
The computers come online and get dhcp. 
They can see all the other devices on the network, including the router and gateway.

However, anything with 10.1.25.xxx cannot connect to the internet. While 10.1.24.xxx does connect fine.

Is there something missing.?

Comment: Did you change the gateway device?

Comment: I'd say you have a masquerading rule for the .24.0/24 or something like this.

Comment: What kind of a rule. There is nothing I can see. However, this is a school and internet access is controlled by the county office. So perhaps they have a rule.

Comment: Good heavens - yes, if you're making network changes on your own, you should definitely be working with the network people before doing anything.

Comment: My hunch is the county office is blocking. Anything with the original ip scheme works (10.1.24.1-254) and connect to the internet just fine. However, anything with 10.1.25.xxx does not get access to internet.  So the network appears to work the same as it did before as long as I don't change the DHCP scope.

Comment: @Damon Why don't you just contact the school's network team and ask for assistance?

Comment: Did you check the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find the local LAN is part of a larger WAN provided by the county. You can't simply change your subnet because it's not yours to change (if that makes sense).

If I'm right, the reason the 2nd half can't see the internet is not so much because it's being blocked, but simply because there's no return route on the other side. Or worse - there may be a route saying that subnet is to go to a router in another physical site!

My advice - revert the changes, then talk to the people who provide the internet/WAN. If you have good reasons (like too many computers) to expend out like that, they shouldn't have any hassles. Be prepared with a list of reasons you need to do this though.